Fontforge: Command Line Argument for clockwise / counterclockwise / direction change
Is there a 'Command Line Argument' in
$ fontforge [-options] [filenames]

for direction change, or clockwise <--> counterclockwise?
I did not find something at 'Command Line Arguments' in
https://fontforge.org/docs/techref/cliargs.html
Since I am working with Gruntfile.js, I need it as a command; I can't open my COLR-glyphs in the Fontforge graphic interface.
